# Send (POST) JSON object to RESTful API using UnityWebRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, unity-game-engine

I am trying to connect my Unity app to a RESTful API I wrote using Javascript and MySQL. At the moment I am having an issue with the unity code which is calling one of my API endpoints - it seems like the Unity code is not connecting to the server at all.

Here is the server endpoint for reference:

```
app.post("/api/users/authenticate/", function(req, res) {

    var queryString = `SELECT UserID, Password FROM UserAccount WHERE UserName = ?`;

    console.log("test");
    console.log(req.body.UserName);
    console.log(req.body.Password);

    connection.query(queryString, [req.body.UserName], function(err, resp) {

        if (!resp[0]) {
            res.send("ER_INCORRECT_USERNAME");
        } else {

            var string = JSON.stringify(resp);
            var jsonResp = JSON.parse(string);

            if (jsonResp[0].Password == req.body.Password) {
                res.send(jsonResp[0].UserID.toString());
            } else {
                res.send("FAILURE_AUTHENTICATED");
            }
        }
    });
    connection.end;
});
```

You can see that this endpoint simply checks to see if the provided parameters are the same as the ones stored in the MySQL database so as to authenticate a player account. Take note of the console.log statements.

Here is the unity code that I am trying to use to POST to this endpoint:

```
public static class PlayerAccountsInterface
    {
         public static IEnumerator AuthenticatePlayer(String username, String password)
        {
            List<IMultipartFormSection> form = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
            form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("UserName", username));
            form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("Password", password));

            UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(InterfaceTools.GetAccountsUrl("authenticate"), form);
            request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            yield return request.Send();
        }   
    }
```

The function InterfaceTools.GetAccountsUrl simply gets the IP address and URL of the server endpoint. This part is definitely correct. The server endpoint is also correct as I've tested it independently using POSTman.

When I run the unity code, no call is being made to the server endpoint. I know this because the three console.log() statements are not triggered.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: How do you call this IEnumerator? via StartCoroutine ?

Comment: In your server side stuff, are you also starting the server with app.listen(somePort)?